# Chat user display overflows wrongly

Tags: bug, design, chat

Pretty serious bug in chat today, when the 32nd person joined the room, their avatar appeared in a strange place:

[image]

I don't think I can continue to use chat until this is fixed.

Comment: You can't use chat until it's fixed? **Bye then!**

Comment: Incidentally, unable to reproduce, are you sure this isn't broken by one of the many scripts you're using?

Comment: @kalina I may struggle through this difficult time.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce the issue. So I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: It happens at random times, a refresh solves it every time for me. the 32 users is not needed, I've seen it break at random numbers.

Comment: I can't repro. what browser/ver/os are you using?

Comment: @Jin Firefox (latest), MacOS (latest)

Comment: This is ArqadeBreaking!